# How to autosize the cells in NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize:) in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

[Image of Alignment that is to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFnia.png)

The need is to right align and center align the collection view cells using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` which I thought could be achieved by using `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize:)` where we can set the frame using `NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItemProvider` and I have achieved it by means of the following code:

```
func createRightAlignedLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout{
        let layoutSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .estimated(80),
            heightDimension: .absolute(34)
        )
        let interItemSpacing : CGFloat = 10
        let lineSpacing : CGFloat = 15
        let itemCount = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize: .init(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
        )) { environment in
            var rightMargin :CGFloat = -1.0
            var yPosition : CGFloat = .zero
            var customItems = [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem]()
            for item in 0..<itemCount {
                 
                let itemSize = self.tags[item].size(withAttributes: [
                    NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
                        ])
                let itemWidth = (itemSize.width + 31)
                rightMargin -= (itemWidth + interItemSpacing)
                if rightMargin < .zero{
                    rightMargin = environment.container.effectiveContentSize.width - itemWidth
                    yPosition += layoutSize.heightDimension.dimension + lineSpacing
                }
               
                let frame = CGRect(x: rightMargin, y: yPosition, width: itemWidth, height: layoutSize.heightDimension.dimension)
                customItems.append(NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: frame))
            }
            return customItems
        }
        
        
        group.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 20)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: config)
        
        return layout
    }
```

Here, I want the itemSize to be calculated by itself, thereby compatible for any kind of element rather only with texts. (Expecting something like layoutAttributesForElements which we get in `func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?` while defining layouts using UICollectionViewLayout.)
[Note: `NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated` doesn't work with custom group]

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: It will help if you include a couple images... what you're getting now and what you are trying to get.

Comment: as I can see it's starting from top-left corner. imo it's too much for a simple task. I will rather use default layout and adjust section insets to position view vertically centred. Try changing `yPosition` and see if it affect cell's position.

Comment: Sure @DonMag !! I have attached the image...This is what I expect, but the only thing is the size is to be auto calculated using `NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated`  therefore I need not calculate the item size for every item

Comment: @BlindNinja I'm trying to use compositional Layout for my entire app...so wanna align the cells using Groups in CompositionalLayout and I don't find a way to add different insets for each group in `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal` or `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical` and that's why went for this `NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom`. Kindly let me know if I could achieve this using vertical or horizontal groups

Answer (score -2):

As long as layout is either horizontal or vertical, we really don't need to group it. Use different layout objects for different collection view.

In your case, you do not need it, use horizontal layout with fixed item height and flexible item width (Use `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview)). Collection view automatically switch to next line once there's not enough space for next item.

In addition to it flip alignment of collection view (Use `flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection` [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/2891099-flipshorizontallyinoppositelayou))